# Height assigned to table cell defaults on selection in tvos

Tags: xcode, uitableview, tvos, tvos9.1

I have a table view in my tvOS app with a custom row height of 250px (which doesn't amount to much). The content of each cell is a text view which has (again) a constant height of 200px. When the table loads, the dimensions look fine on initial render.

[image: On render]

But when i actual focus on the cell, it defaults to some initial height:

[image: On selection]

I've tried to give the table view an `estimatedRowHeight` on load:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 250
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Even implementing the row height methods in the `UITableViewDelegate` doesn't help:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

I think i'm missing something really simple, but i can't think of anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Directly return a number, like `return 50.0`.